# New construction subfloor unlevel

Tags: floor

So noticed my floor is unlevel in a new construction house. It is only sinking at the 2x4. Is in lake county Indiana.

I look in the basement and see at the subfloor seam it did not hit the joist so they nailed an extra 2x4 in.  Is this against code? How should it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to hit the joist because your joists are staggered.

Comment: Thanks , I had a feeling it was not sufficient . The builder just wants to push the 2x4 higher and re nail. 2x10 with screws sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2' span from the adjacent joist on only half the width of the sheet, that block is more than adequate. If there are a half dozen framing nails in it it'll never move. You could park a piano there and it would hold. The key is the fasteners, not the height of the block.

Now, you mentioned an out-of-level condition and failed to explain where. (Edit: I see it now in a comment.) I'll assume that it's the end of the sheet over that block. If so, the block should be raised or shimmed to bring the sheet level with the others.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t trust nails to hold that. I would remove the screws to the top of the 2x4 and then remove the 2x4. I would then sister a 2x10 (that’s what the joist looks like) to the joist and bolt them together or at least use plenty of structural screws. Make sure the floor is level before joining everything.

Comment: @isherwood not even deflect a little? They might be tiling above that spot.

Comment: If they're tiling there's another layer of subfloor going in anyway, which will span everything. It's not a concern if it's brought to level.